# next/prev links in horizontal animation page

Tags: jquery, button

I made on my page something similiar to that:
http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/horizontal-animate-page-to-id-jquery.html

It works perfect except the fact i'm strugling on making prev/next buttons. I tried few ways but it seems not to work, anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way, in my opinion, would be to increment the anchors and their relative content selectors (eg. id: content-1/nav-1, content-2/nav-2, etc.). all your nav items would have a general class of `.nav` and all your content holders would have general class of `.content`. this way, you could do something like...

```
$(" [next/previous button] ").click(function(){
   if ( $(this).attr("id") == "next" ) {
      [call function to ADD 1 to the current content/nav]
   } else if ( $(this).attr("id") == "previous" ) {
      [call function to SUBTRACT 1 from the current content/nav]
   }
});
```